# "NameError" when supplying variable name to input() prompt

Tags: exception, python-3.x, input, nameerror

I have this simple bit of code I can't get to work any advice?

```
a = 2
b = 4
c = input()
d = 0
d = c + 5
print(d)
```

Say I input `a`, so `2`, I should get `7`. But I don't. This Python 3. Using Wing IDE 101 (ver. 5) here. I get this as my error output.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
builtins.NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Comment: This is the entirety of your script?  You are positive you are using python3? And you are only typing `a` at the prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are using Python 3? In python 2.x you can do it by explictly evaluating an string expression with the [`eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) function:

```
 c = eval(raw_input()) # Python 2.7
 c = eval(input()) # Python 3.x
```

In Python 3.x [`input()`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#input) will convert the input in a string and won't raise that error (`NameError`). It will raise a `TypeError` instead, because you cannot concatenate `str` and `int` that way.

Comment: Python 3 for sure. I installed it on my computer, running Windows 7 is that matters.

Comment: I'm getting this as my error: File "c:\Users\USER\Documents\untitled-2.py", line 3, in <module>
  c = eval(raw_input())

builtins.NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined

Comment: Mmmm if you are using Python 3.x then try: `eval(input())`. See edit.

Comment: I did refer back to my original post

Comment: I did what you did and it worked but the thing is say I enter a and I get 7. After I type in a again I only get 2. So it is not repetitive, any help there

Comment: Just note that: `eval("a")` is the same as `a`, so you are indeed doing: `c = a`

Comment: Also note that `eval` is slow and an _extreme_ security risk, as you can execute arbitrary python code with it (e.g. delete your harddisk / read your private files)...

Answer (score 0):

you can just try c = raw_input()

Comment: Notice the `python-3.x` tag on the question?  That means this is `python3` where `raw_input` has been removed and replaced with `input`.